# How to install libltdl3 to make iscan work?

Tags: printing, scanner, epson

I changed my printer from an Epson sx110 to an xp-205. The scanner never worked.

Under Windows it works perfectly, but I want to make it run under Linux because I use Linux more than Windows. Is there a way to make it work?

The libltdl3 broke the dependencies of iscan 2.29 that is the only one you can find on Epson website ,the sane-scan-detect find the scanner the scanimage -L not and same doing appen when using simple scan and the other programs,NO Scanner found bla bla ,...

The printer works fine. Why is that problem resolved in any other Ubuntu version? I see lot of posts, for Debian, and other distros that make think I found "funny thing and easy to fix using a hammer"

Comment: Alex - if you trying to respond, you need to register your accounts - please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page and request an account merger.  Once done, you will be able to edit your question with further information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you've downloaded the wrong version of iscan. There are two versions available on the Epson website, one for ltdl3 en one for **ltdl7**. For Ubuntu 8.10 or newer you have to use the **ltdl7** version.